# Animation not stop with common Animation Static class in Android and Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, animation, xamarin, view, xamarin.android

I am facing issue with Animation in Android, I started Animation with specific event and i want to stop that animation with specific event, but i not stop. I created a common Animation class with static function like startAnimation() and stopAnimation() because i used same animation with multiple views with different screens.

Please give your valuable solution and suggestion.

My code as below in Xamarin.Android.

```
public static class AnimationUtil
    {
        private const int DURATION = 200;
        private const int DELAY = 2000;

        public static AnimatorSet StartPulsingAnimation(this View view)
        {   
            ObjectAnimator scaleX = ObjectAnimator.OfFloat(view, "scaleX", 1.0f, 1.5f);
            ObjectAnimator scaleY = ObjectAnimator.OfFloat(view, "scaleY", 1.0f, 1.5f);

            scaleX.RepeatMode = ValueAnimatorRepeatMode.Reverse;
            scaleX.RepeatCount = ValueAnimator.Infinite;

            scaleY.RepeatMode = ValueAnimatorRepeatMode.Reverse;
            scaleY.RepeatCount = ValueAnimator.Infinite;

            AnimatorSet scaleDown = new AnimatorSet();
            scaleDown.Play(scaleX).With(scaleY);
            scaleDown.SetDuration(DURATION);            
            scaleDown.Start();

            return scaleDown;
        }

        public static void StopPulsingAnimation(this View view, AnimatorSet scaleDown)
        {
            if (scaleDown == null)
                return;

            view.ClearAnimation();

            scaleDown.Cancel();           
            scaleDown.RemoveAllListeners();
            scaleDown = null;
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you provide code what calling this?

Comment: AnimationSet scaleDown = btnClear.StartPulsingAnimation();

Comment: I checked your code, it works fine. Could you show how do you stop animation? What event are you using?

Comment: What is `btnClear`? The `StartPulsingAnimation` is a static method, you should use `AnimationUtil.StartPulsingAnimation()`, please show more codes.